# How to turn off formatting marks for Word for Mac?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have Word for Mac 2011, version 14.4.5. I have currently turned on the formatting marks (dots for spaces, arrows for tabs, paragraph marks, etc.). I want to turn the marks off but I don't know how. All the information I can find online is for the Windows version of Word.

Comment: Did you check `Word > Preferences > View > Non-printing Characters`?

Comment: @CharlieRB That works, you should submit that as an answer.

Comment: To everybody: any idea why I got a downvote?  Is this question "too easy" for this site?  I spent a long time Googling around to try and find the answer but could not.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Word > Preferences > View > Non-printing Characters` and uncheck what you do not want displayed.